# selecting values excluding null values using select all button in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a dojo script which helps me do a select all options for a list

The script is as follows

```
function checkAll(tableId){
   dojo.query("input[name^='TBL_SELECTION']", dojo.byId(tableId)).forEach(function(input, index) {
      if (!input.checked) {
         selectRow(input, 'multiple', true, index, null, false); 
      }
   });
}
```

Now in my list if there is an empty or null value present which had the checkbox(select option) present.

e.g.

check box-option 1 value

check box-option 2 value

check box-option 3(is null or empty)

check box-option 4 value

I dont want to select the option which is null when I am clicking a select all option.

How do I do this in dojo.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you use a dijit.form.CheckBox, you can check it's value, and iterate over it if null:

```
var myCheckBox = new dijit.form.CheckBox({name: "checkBox1", value: "value1"});

if(myCheckBox.get('value')!== null){
    myCheckBox.set('checked', true);
}
```